# Implicit conversion of function type

Tags: scala

I'm going through [this JavaFX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm), using Scala as the implementation language, and ran into an issue with my implicit conversion not being picked up:

```
class HelloApplication extends Application {
  import HelloApplication._

  override def start(stage: Stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Hello World!")
    val btn = new Button()
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'")
    btn.setOnAction(function2EventHandler(buttonPressed))

    val root = new StackPane()
    root.getChildren.add(btn)
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250))
    stage.show()
  }

  def buttonPressed(ev: ActionEvent) {
    println("Hello World!")
  }
}

object HelloApplication {
  implicit def function2EventHandler[A <: Event](f: A => Unit): EventHandler[A] = 
    new EventHandler[A] {
      override def handle(t: A) = f(t)
    }
}
```

When I change this line

```
btn.setOnAction(function2EventHandler(buttonPressed))
```

to

```
btn.setOnAction(buttonPressed)
```

I'm getting a compilation error. Can you point me to what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using the JavaFX that ships with JDK 7 and Scala 2.11.4.

Comment: And why do you need to change that line?

Comment: @amahfouz It's just a learning exercise for me, and I would like to understand why an implicit conversion doesn't work in this specific case. I also feel this might be of general interest, since code that uses SAM-types will definitely see an increase before Scala 2.12 comes out and this pattern would make it much easier to work with that in the meantime IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First what I see, that: `buttonPressed` is an expression of method type NOT function type

```
def buttonPressed(ev: ActionEvent) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

I think you need to use eta expansion (§6.26.5 Eta Expansion [ScalaReference](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)) before implicit conversion:

```
btn.setOnAction(buttonPressed _)
```

Comment: You are right, but quoting the buttonPressed event doesn't make it clear it's actually a method, not a function.